# White space between div's

Tags: html, css

I've tried to make the white space disappear to no avail! Below I've pasted my code. The problem occurs between `.jumbotron` and `.footer`. I know it must be something with the margin or padding, maybe with the `.jumbotron h2`.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Niall's Portfolio</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio src="/Users/kmahford/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Hiatus Kaiyote/Choose Your Weapon/16 Only Time All the Time_ Making Friends with Studio Owl.m4a" autoplay></audio>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <h1>ZAH</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
              <ul class="pull-right">
                 <li><a href="AboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
                 <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>making <span>rustic</span> <span id="and">and</span> <span>modern</span> meet.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy; Che Co.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Jumbotron */

.jumbotron {
    height: 600px;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?q=80&fm=jpg&s=a4598570a3286ea23369fdefe46953ba") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;}
.jumbotron h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1E91B2;
    padding-top: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;}
.jumbotron span {
    font-weight: 800;}
.jumbotron #and {
    color: #FF8208;
    font-weight: 400;}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I was trying to include a screenshot and couldn't figure it out in time (have to run do some errands), but basically there's about a 20px white space between my jumbotron and footer section. Can't figure out how to get rid of it!

Comment: The jumbotron class has a 30px bottom margin by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jumbotron class has a 30px bottom margin by default. Remove it:

```
div.jumbotron {margin-bottom:0;}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/85a5f0hg/1/)**

Note that this *is* the reason for the spacing issue and you have to override Bootstrap's CSS with your own by making your CSS more specific in order for it to take effect.

Comment: unfortunately no dice

Comment: @Zah - I saw the fiddle you created and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that within your `footer`, the `<p>` has a margin that is pushing the footer down.

What you want instead is to add this piece of CSS:

```
.footer p{
    margin:0; 
}
```

Comment: I added this but it didn't fix the white space... .footer {height: 60px; width: 100%; background: #000; color: #fff;} .footer p {margin: 0 0; padding: 20px 0 0 200px;}

Comment: Try setting padding to 0 as well.

Comment: Try to use this: `.jumbotron { margin-bottom: 0; }`

Comment: Why? there is no padding which you need to set to zero @David Li

Comment: Because look at his comment. He set padding to 20px 0 0 200px

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right you should change on the  `jumbotron`class the `margin`, like this:

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron{
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/obn2yav1/1/)

if you also don't want the whitespace on the bottom of your page, set the `margin` from the `p` tag also to zero.